# I know the sudo password, can I use sudo and install software without logging out and switching to the admin user?

Tags: terminal, password, permission, catalina, user-account

I have two accounts on my MacBook (runs Catalina 15.1), one is admin, one is non-admin.

Both are mine, so I know the password for both.

Sometimes when I want to run some 'sudo' command or use the GUI to install some software, I would like to not have to log out and log into the admin account. Is there any way I can just do this by entering the password to the admin acccount?

Comment: Strictly speaking this is no real duplicate but an invalid question. It contains two different questions - only one is reflected in the headline (after editing). 1. Priv elevation in the shell 2. Priv elevation in the GUI.

Comment: @ankii I've rolled back the edit, it changed too much.

Comment: I think this should be upvoted highly - and possibly closed. It really is two different questions. How do I choose a different user in GUI and How do I choose a different user in a shell - but the rule about one question per question is to get a good answer. Here, it’s feasible to answer both clearly and usefully and then link to the “canonical” here’s how to su (and not sudo) and the “canonical” - enter the admin user name to use the admin password.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can do it. You don't need to logout as both the GUI and the shell allow you to choose a different user to run in a non-admin account.

- When it pops up for a password in GUI, enter the short `echo $USER` or long (what it shows in top right corner) admin account and then the admin password.
- In terminal type, `su username` where username is your admin account name: `echo $USER` in admin account. After which, it will ask you to provide a password. This changes the shell to an admin shell and then you can sudo or just do. For spaces in `username` variable, for e.g. network accounts `su "foo bar"` to be used.

There are some more methods listed in these posts, like using `sudoers`, `login` etc.

- [How do I run sudo command from standard account?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/100703/how-do-i-run-sudo-command-from-standard-account)
- [Run sudo From Non-Admin Account](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/126397/run-sudo-from-non-admin-account?noredirect=1&lq=1)